# Мethod DELETE laravel, какие есть варианты удаления?

Tags: laravel

Работаю на laravel 5.7
1) Создал GET роут, и и проходя по ссылке все удалил:

```
Route::get('products/deleteCart/{id}','ProductsController@deleteCart')->name('cartDelete');
```

ссылка:

```
<a class="cart_quantity_delete" href="{{route('cart.destroy',['id'=>$item['data']['id']])}}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

Можно ли ресурсные маршруты удалять без формы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ларавел рекомендовано удалять через форму:

А) рекомендовано.

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', ['id'=>$item['data']['id']]) }}" method="post">
      @method('DELETE')
      @csrf
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

B) или такой

```
<form action="{{ url('/cart', ['id'=>$item['data']['id']] ) }}" method="post">
  {!! method_field('delete') !!}
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

3) или установить компонент форм:   composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"

```
{{ Form::open(['route'=>['categories.destroy', $category->id],'method'=>'delete']) }}
    <button onclick ="return confirm(' Вы уверены?')" type ="submit" class="delete">
    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    </button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```